# Edit listview item width

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm adding an image to a listview.items and I'm wondering if there's a way to change the width of each item? Right now it spans the whole list view and I'd like to make it the width of the image so I can fit a few per row.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the columns, you have the option of setting their widths.

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Assigned To", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Start Date", 112, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Date Began", 112, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Date Completed", 112, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Due Date", 112, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Description", 375, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("CR", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
listView1.Columns.Add("Confirmed By", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

Comment: that's the WinForms ListView control not for Windows Store apps

Comment: Oh my fault, I didn't notice the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think the specific answer to your question is that you just need to set [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.stretch.aspx)=None for the image asset you've added as a ListViewItem.  For instance, the following XAML leads to the display you see after it:

```
    <ListView x:Name="lv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  SelectionChanged="lv_SelectionChanged">
        <ListViewItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Assets/SmallLogo.png"  Stretch="None" />
                <Image Source="/Assets/SmallLogo.png"  Stretch="None" />
                <Image Source="/Assets/SmallLogo.png"  Stretch="None" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <Border BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="1" Background="Red">
                <Image Source="/Assets/Logo.png" Stretch="None" />
            </Border>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

[image]

But this is a brittle solution since you'll need to populate each ListViewItem with potentially variable number of items inside some other container (like the StackPanel, here), if - as you mention - you want to fit a 'few per row'.

Depending on the effect you're looking for, you may want to consider some alternative control approaches like GridView and the VariableSizedWrapGrid.  Take a look at [Jerry Nixon's post](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html) for more flexible and appealing presentations you can achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think a gridview will work better but I have a question

The items aren't taking up the whole row but they're going downward how do I make them fill up a row then make a new row.

Comment: You'll need to set up an ItemsPanelTemplate for the GridView and set Orientation to Horizontal

Comment: Thanks! One last question. I'd like some text on the bottom of the images that go into the GridView but the Image control has no content or text property. Is there someway I can add that to the Image control?

Comment: You'd need to add a TextBlock control. Make each GridViewItem a StackPanel (vertical) that includes the image and a TextBlock.

Comment: Oh its that simple? I'll give it a shot.